# Missing Dependency: Castle.DynamicProxy2 after install LINQtoExecl from NuGet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies

I recently added the package LinqToExcel to my .net 4 WPF project and now when entering the designer I am presented with the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.DynamicProxy2, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

LinqToExcel only has one dependency - log4net, which it installed as part of the NuGet process. Both are referenced and set to Copy Local. I'm not sure where the reference to Castle is coming from or how to go about fixing it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: May be worth pointing out the the program will build and run fine!

Comment: Just a quick check, go to the properties of the project make sure you have it set to .Net Framework 4 and not .Net Framework 4 Client Profile.